# One of two FlatLists not rendering items in same component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have two FlatLists in my react native component. They are filled with similar data and about 80 items for the second FlatList. When the first FlatList reaches 11 items or more (I'm adding dynamically items to the first FlatList), the second one stops rendering items, and it is empty even if the choice for the filter is correct.
This is the first FlatList:

```
<FlatList
  style={styles.flatList}
  data={todaySuggestions}
  renderItem={this.renderSuggestionItem}
  keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
  extraData={this.props}
/>
```

And the second one is:

```
<FlatList
 style={styles.flatList}
 data={data.filter(item => !completedItems.find(item1 => item1.id === item.id).completed)}
 renderItem={this.renderFurtherSuggestionItem}
 keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
 extraData={this.props}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this one by adding another condition for filter, removing it from renderFurtherSuggestionItem function. In the other case, FlatList won't notice change of the data.

Answer (score 0):

when state change, Flatlist don't rerender again. if you want to rerender it again should use :

```
     <FlatList
       data:{yourData}
       extraData:{this.state.yourState}
       renderItem={this.yourRenderItem}
/>
```

instead of yourState you should use the state that when it changed, you need to rerender your flatlist.