# Data not being displayed in one of two FlatLists in the same component

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, listitem

I have a component with two TextInputs. Under each TextInput, there is a FlatList which gets rendered when the user types in some characters (the actual rendering happens in ListItem, a module from react-native elements). For the first FlatList, everything works fine - it is rendered as expected. The problem is with the second FlatList - I cannot get it to render. See this gif to understand what I mean: https://gph.is/g/E1G1jnx

I've tried using the "extraData" prop as advised in [One of two FlatLists not rendering items in same component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737070/one-of-two-flatlists-not-rendering-items-in-same-component) , but it didn't fix the issue.

I know that the problem doesn not come from onChangeAddress(address) being an async function. I used a static dataset and still it wouldn't render.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, FlatList, ImageBackground, Image } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

 class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            jobInputValue: '',
            addressInputValue: '',
            showJobsDropdown: false,
            showAddressesDropdown: false,
            jobsList: this.props.jobTitles.results,
            addressPredictions: []
     };
  }

async onChangeAddress(address) {
//fetch the data from the API
//filteredAddresses stores the data from the API
if (filteredAddresses.length > 0) {
            this.setState({
               addressPredictions: filteredAddresses,
               showAddressesDropdown: true
            })
        }
    }

}

  render() {
    return (
    <ImageBackground style={styles.bkgImage} source={require('../assets/homepage_background.jpg')}>
        <TextInput 
            style={styles.jobTextInput}
            value={this.state.jobInputValue}
            placeholder='Ce job cauți?'
            onChangeText={(jobInputValue) => this.setState({jobInputValue}, this.checkJobsDropdown(jobInputValue))}/>
                <FlatList
                data={this.state.jobsList}
                style={this.state.showJobsDropdown ? styles.jobsDropdownStyle : styles.dropdownHiddenStyle}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <ListItem
                        title={item}
                        containerStyle={{paddingBottom: -4}}
                        titleProps={{ style: styles.dropdownItemStyle}}
                        onPress={() => this.setState({jobInputValue: item}, this.hideJobsDropdown())}
                    />
                )}
                keyExtractor={item => item}
            />

        <TextInput 
            style={styles.addressTextInput}
            value={this.state.addressInputValue}
            placeholder='La ce adresă locuiești?'
            onChangeText={addressInputValue => this.onChangeAddress(addressInputValue)}
            />
//the issue is with the FlatList below
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.addressPredictions}
                extraData={this.state}
                style={this.state.showAddressesDropdown ? styles.addressDropdownStyle : styles.dropdownHiddenStyle}
                renderItem={({ addressItem, index }) => (
                    <ListItem
                        title={addressItem}
                        containerStyle={{paddingBottom: -4}}
                        titleProps={{style: styles.dropdownItemStyle}}
                        onPress={() => this.setState({addressInputValue: addressItem}, this.hideAddressesDropdown())}
                    />
                )}
                keyExtractor={(addressItem, index) => index.toString()}
            />
        <Button 
            title="CAUTĂ"
            type="outline"
            underlayColor={colors.red}
            titleStyle={styles.buttonTitleStyle}
            color={colors.red}
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            onPress={this.printState}
            />

    </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Think you could make a reproducible [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/)?

Comment: @iuliu.net, please find the Expo Snack at https://snack.expo.io/@narcis/jobzy .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the destructuring of the data for rendering the items of your second flatlist:

```
renderItem={({ addressItem, index }) => (
                <ListItem
                    title={addressItem}
                    containerStyle={{paddingBottom: -4}}
                    titleProps={{style: styles.dropdownItemStyle}}
                    onPress={() => this.setState({addressInputValue: addressItem}, this.hideAddressesDropdown())}
                />
            )}
```

`({ addressItem, index })` <- there's no `addressItem` available here. You have to replace that with `item`, as Flatlist offers an object with the `{ item: Object, index: Number, separators: object }` structure as the param to your renderList callback.